# Noahide studying creation

Tags: gentiles, torah-study, creation, noahidism

Can Noahide study matters related to creation like first day of creation, commentaries of Ramban, Rashi and others? If so what are limits to such study and how much can one speculate about it?

Comment: Do you have a reason to think that there are any restrictions?

Comment: Sanhedrin 59a R. Johanan said: A heathen who studies the Torah deserves death

Comment: But then I saw some chabad article there is connection between 7 laws and seven days of creation which sugest it might be relevant for Noahide as well.

Comment: @WNguyen - I wouldn't throw a Noahide into the category of heathen. A "heathen" seems to be someone who is a heretic, or one who believes in a foreign G-d. I think it is acceptable for him to study the Creation study, with Rashi and all the other commentaries included!

Comment: @WNguyen - You are actually incorrect because the Gemoro actually says: עובד כוכבים שעוסק בתורה חייב מיתה שנאמר (דברים לג, ד) תורה צוה לנו משה מורשה לנו מורשה ולא להם. Note that "Oved Kochavim" means a *worshipper of stars*, not a Gentile or Noahide.

Comment: @ezra with all due respect, the proof text you quoted applies equally to all non-Jews regardless of their actions or beliefs. מורשה לנו מורשה ולא להם

Comment: @LN6595 Reviewed. Agreed. :)

Comment: The question is: Are non-Jews murdered for studying Jewish topics? Yes, they probably shouldn't, but isn't murdering them seems unnecessary?

Comment: @Turk Deserving of death =/= a command to murder.

Comment: @user6591 A murderer deserves death. A non-Jew with good intentions who study Talmud does not. Many non-Jews wonder what we're hiding. I'd rather let them read and know. Otherwise, they'd think we hide anti-non-Jewish topics, which turns them into anti-semites.

Comment: @Turk You are in fact confusing them about what we Jews who believe and keep to the Talmud actually believe. As you like to do. My point was to clarify that when the Talmud states they are 'deserving death', this statement is not the same as saying Sanhedrin or the like is commanded to kill them. There are instances when language like this is used for Jews and non-jews alike and means they deserve to die, sometimes with the implication that God will end their lives, sometimes not even that. Don't you go and present it to mean that a Jew must kill a non-Jew who learns Torah. That is wrong.

Comment: @user6591 Yes, we agree entirely. Thank you for writing.

Answer (score 5):

According to [Sefer Sheva Mitzvot Hashem](http://store.kehotonline.com/prodinfo.asp?number=HL-SHEV1) on the subject, to study the two Torah parashios (bereshis and Noah) are basically related to Noahide Laws in general. See there on *Yesodos ha-emunah*, perek 5:3 (*rough translation below*):

> It is **permitted** for a gentile to read the *Tanakh*,
>   even with traditional expositions of the *pshat* in order to
>   correctly understant its *pesukim*.

The limits of such study is that he still continues forbidden to delve into study of its text, trying to arrive at inner explanations of the verses (since pshat oriented commentary doesn't do that). See hagahot yavetz on sanhedrin 59a.